# Como verificar ganhador no jogo da velha

Tags: c, algoritmo, jogos

Estou fazendo um jogo da velha em C, quero saber como verificar qual o jogador que ganhou, verificando as linhas na horizontal e vertical e nas diagonais.

Aqui esta o meu programa feito até agora:

```
#define tam 3 
void desenhaTabuleiro(char M[tam][tam]);  
void zeraTabuleiro(char M[tam][tam]) 
int joga(char M[tam][tam], int player);
int testaTabuleiro(char M[tam][tam], int linJogada, int colJogada);
int main() {
    char M[tam][tam];
    int player=0;
    int retornoJoga;
    int numJogada = 1;

    zeraTabuleiro(M);
    desenhaTabuleiro(M);

    while(1){
        retornoJoga=joga(M, player);
        if(retornoJoga == 0)
            player=!player;
        if(numJogada >= 9){
            printf("\n###FIM DE JOGO###");
            break;  
        }
        else
            numJogada++;

        desenhaTabuleiro(M);
    }

    return 0;
}

int testaTabuleiro(char M[tam][tam], int linJogada, int colJogada){
    if (linJogada < 0 || linJogada > 2 || colJogada < 0 || colJogada > 2){
        printf("#### JOGADA INVALIDA ####\n#MSG: Out of tabuleiro!!!\n\n");
        return -1; 
    }
    if(M[linJogada][colJogada] != 'V'){
        printf("#### JOGADA INVALIDA ####\n#MSG: Esta posicao ja existe\n\n");
        return -1;  
    }
    s
    return 0;
}

int joga(char M[tam][tam], int player){
    int linJogada, colJogada;
    int retornoTeste;
    int retornoPosicao;

    printf(":::: Player %d ::::\nEscolha a linha e a coluna: ",player+1);
    scanf("%d %d",&linJogada,&colJogada);

    retornoTeste=testaTabuleiro(M, linJogada, colJogada);
    if(retornoTeste == -1){
        return -1;
    }

    if(retornoTeste == 0){
        if(player)
            M[linJogada][colJogada] = 'O';
        else
            M[linJogada][colJogada] = 'X';

        return 0;
    }
}


void zeraTabuleiro(char M[tam][tam]){
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
        for(j=0; j<tam; j++){
            M[i][j] = 'V';
        }
    }

}



void desenhaTabuleiro(char M[tam][tam]){
    int i,j;

    //system("cls");

    for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
        for(j=0; j<tam; j++){
            if(j==0){
                printf(" %c ",M[i][j]);
            }
            else{
                if(j==1){
                    printf("| %c |",M[i][j]);
                }
                else{
                    if(j==2){
                        printf(" %c \n",M[i][j]);
                        if(i!=2){
                            printf("-----------\n",i,j);
                        }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Aqui esta o código que tentei para fazer esta verificação

```
int vencedor(char M[tam][tam]){
int i, j;
int soma = 0;
for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
    for(j=0; j<tam; j++){
        if(M[i][j] == 'O'){
            soma += 1;
        }
    }
    if(soma == 3){
        break;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        soma = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Mas o que você tentou? Quais problemas você enfrentou? Da forma como está, parece apenas um caso de "resolva o problema para mim"...

Comment: vou colocar o código que tenho

Comment: Ainda não consigo ver o que você tentou para resolver o problema... Coloque também os códigos que deram errado... Ou ainda não tentou nada?

Comment: Acabei de colocar o código que tentei

Answer (score 2):

A tua função `vencedor()` não tem instrução `return`.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema